# Using NUnit to test script and show output

Tags: nunit

I am learning how to use NUnit to test some scripts written within asp.net in c#. Does anyone know how to tell if the script has pass/failed on NUnit, as in what the test result output is.

Or does anyone know any good websites, where I can read up on learning how to use NUnit?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=quickStart&r=2.4

http://nunitasp.sourceforge.net/tutorial/index.html

Lots of more links c/o Google. Your question does not enough information - 'scripts written within asp.net' is very vague.

Comment: basically I am trying to create a test script to test a login page in asp.net using c#. But I am a beginner in using Nunit, I need good tutorials.

Comment: @dipesh - have a look at the links above.. you should find lots of material online.

Answer (score 0):

When using VS with NUnit, you need to open your Test Explorer window.  In there, you'll see a pass/fail for tests as well as output.